# How can I force Azure function to output JSON to browsers

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function setup with this source:

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {
    //this is the entire source, seriously
    context.done(null, {favoriteNumber : 3});
};
```

When I use a tool like postman to visit it I get a nice JSON output, exactly like I want:

```
{
  "favoriteNumber": 3
}
```

The problem is when I visit it in a browser (chrome, firefox, etc) I see:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><KeyValueOfstringanyType><Key>favoriteNumber</Key><Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:int">3</Value></KeyValueOfstringanyType></ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType>
```

[image]
How can I force azure to always give me a json output, regardless of the request headers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried setting the response object's `Content-Type` explicitly to `application\json` ?

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {
    res = {
        body: { favoriteNumber : 3},
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

context.done(null, res);
};
```

By default, Functions are configured for content negotiation. When you call your function, Chrome is sending a header like

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

so, it's asking for XML and it gets it back.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfect, it had a syntax error so I edited to fix it. Where did you find this, I was searching around for 20+ minutes and only found answers for .net applications

Comment: Thank you! "By default, Functions are configured for content negotiation" Can a function be forced-configured to use JSON? I can't find that setting.